# редактирование json в php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть занесенный в ассоциативный массив JSON,
нужно в конец добавить новый массив.
пытаюсь использовать:

```
    $rtt = array();
    $rtt['nodes']['x'] = $xp;//какие-то значения
    $rtt['nodes']['y'] = $yp;
    //$tar и есть этот массив
    $tar->entites[$fl]['Triggers'] = $rtt;//сохраняем

    //Это содержимое конца массива
         [""]=> //Как это убрать, или как правильно вставить новый массив
         array(1) {
           ["Triggers"]=>//Чтобы начинался этот блок от сюда
              array(1) {
                ["nodes"]=>
                array(2) {
                 ["x"]=>
                 float(99.58)
                 ["y"]=>
                 float(353)
                 }
                }
               }
```

Comment: $fl не имеет значения. Поменять `$tar->entites[$fl]['Triggers'] = $rtt;` - `$tar->entites[]['Triggers'] = $rtt;` или присвоить значение $fl перед этим.

Answer (score 2):

```
$tar->entites['Triggers'] = $rtt;
```

или так или

```
$tar->entites['Triggers'][] = $rtt;
```

но судя по всему первое...